# Burning bootloader

Tags: atmega328, pcb-design

I'm using arduino atmega 328p and currently using on custom PCB
I programmed using the arduino board and take the IC and migrated to my custom PCB
currently the program run well on the arduino board but after i tried to run it in my custom PCB  and i found it didn't worked
im using along with 16000 mhz oscillator with 22n capacitor

[image]

as shown this is my schematic for my PCB

[image]

this is my trace for my PCB board

so is this problem caused by my schematics or i didn't upload the bootloader?

Comment: You have no decoupling capacitors. Your crystal layout is abysmal.

Comment: what do you mean by abysmal and decoupling capacitors?

Comment: By abysmal I mean: crystal is too far from the chip pins. The capacitors are poorly grounded. The traces are too angular. There is no guard ring or ground pour. If you don't know what decoupling capacitors are then you need to go and learn the basics of digital circuit design.

Comment: Did you use 22nF with the crystal?  You need 22pF.  16 MHz  = 16 x 10^6 = 16,000,000 Hz (not hz).  16000mhz is not correct, that's like 16000 x 10^-3 = 16 Hz.  M = Mega = 1 million.  m = milli = 1/1000.  u = micro = 1/1000000.

Comment: I like to give folks the benefit of the doubt, and correct when needed.  Must be the engineer/coach in me, and plenty of non-native English/American/engineer interactions.

Comment: oh okay i see, it seems I need to use the 22pF rathe than 22nF, get the crystal corrected so it would near to the chips, but what did u mean the capacitor was poorly grounded? is it means i need to make a larger ground traces for the capacitors?

Comment: You should use a ground plane, not ground traces. Reduces the impedance.

Comment: [Here is a good design](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/f/166/p/312483/2286056#2286056). The final posting - right at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Schematic corrections:

Missing 0.1uF caps on VCC, AREF pins.

AREF pin connected to 5V - don't do that. It will connect internally using the ADC Mux if used.

C1, C6 need to be 22pF as noted earlier.

Xtal and C1, C6 should be right next to the chip as noted, with no traces going under the xtal.

Board should have Gnd plane anywhere there is not a trace.

Use Vias to connect top & bottom Gnd planes.

Do not use traces to connect all the Gnds - have pins connect to the Gnd planes instead.

Add a 1uF or 10uF electrolytic capacitor where power comes into the board, especially if the power leads will be long.

Comment: can i have a full schematic drawing include the components as u listed?

Comment: Sure,  http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf  This has a resonator instead of the crystal and caps, and also shows a voltage regulator.

Comment: i currently using atmega 328p ... is this usable for atmega328p instead atmega328?

Comment: 328p is the standard chip used on Arduino Uno, Nano, Promini. That is what the bootloaded is set up for.  328 has different 'signature bytes' and uses a little more power.

Comment: i just looked at my custom board that i just make. i found out that the pin 20 doesnt have any trace connected anywhere. is this can be a problem that causes my arduino didn't work?

Comment: Yes! The chip needs power to work. VCC and AVCC both need to connect to 5V, both should have a 0.1uF cap connected to them also.